# Why can't chrome "load plugin" for YouTube? (Which I assume is adobe flash player)

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.68 [which is supposed](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.in/2013/02/stable-channel-update.html) to have fixed a recent ["can't load plug-in" error](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173790).

I have tried the instructions on the page http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#main__I_am_unable_to_view_Flash_content__How_do_I_get_Flash_Player_to_turn_on_ to turn flash player on and I have restarted my browser and it still gives me this error. How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite [claims that the latest update](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2013/02/stable-channel-update.html) has fixed things ...

> The Stable channel has been updated to 24.0.1312.68 for Linux. This build contains the fix for Pepper Flash.

people may still be seeing the "can't load plug-in" error.

One workaround is to disable the Pepper Flash and use Adobe's if it's available. The Chrome browser will "see" the Adobe NPAPI Flash plug-in if it exists in `~/.mozilla/plugins`.

For people who have installed Chromium as well, along with its goodies, the Flash plug-in will be in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`. So just copy it from there to `~/.mozilla/plugins`.

In the long term, Adobe's policy is to not develop Flash for Linux anymore. And so the latest Flash will be the Pepper Flash which comes with Chrome. Unfortunately, it's still highly "experimental".

---

**Edit**: A way to still use Pepper Flash is [described here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/PEgELQH5zcg/c5lHKwslBcwJ):

- Start Chrome
- In `chrome://plugins`, enable Pepper Flash in case you disabled it (as suggested above)
- Close the Chrome browser
- Open a file manager and enable viewing of hidden files and folders (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Either delete the `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash` folder or rename it to something else.
- Restart Chrome. Now Pepper Flash should work.

**Further edit** 20130208: Version 24.0.1312.**69** worked out of the box for me and didn't need the "delete the ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash folder" hack.

Comment: I am running 24.0.1312.68, I just upgraded it and still YouTube and thus flash refuses to work.

Comment: Google Chrome 24.0.1312.68 (Official Build 180326) 
OS Linux 
WebKit 537.17 (@140072)
JavaScript V8 3.14.5.6
Flash 11.5.31.138
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.68 Safari/537.17
Command Line  /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path /home/brentonhorne/.config/google-chrome/Default
Variations 5666f941-fd526c81

Comment: OK, so what does that mean to me? As far as fixing this? I must confess I know little if anything about programming & PCs in general just some basic terminal commands, what's good hardware wise, roughly and basic PC functions.

Comment: I've added an edit that allowed me to use Pepper Flash. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://plugins` and set your setting like the following screenshot and refresh your page:

[image]